# Managing RSS feeds

Tags: xml, rss, blogs

I am developing for a website that has an event "listing" service. It uses an rss feed (located at the web root under the name 'rss.xml') to give an RSS feed of the events to users who are interested in the service.

I've been tasked with developing a blog for the website. I have the blog piece done, but I'm not sure the best way to integrate an RSS feed for the blog in to the website. Ideally, in the future some people will be visiting to read the blog while others may be visiting to use the service.

What's the best way to integrate the blog RSS feed in to the website? Do I combine the event listings AND blog RSS feeds in to the main rss.xml or do I need to pick one? I also wonder how this plays in to using services like feedburner to track subscription, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to pick a primary and a backup.  Since you're probably making money off your events and not your blog, I'd make the events rss your primary.  So your events would be rss.xml and your blog would be blogrss.xml

Also I advise adding a link tag on your page for your RSSs

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Company&#39;s Events (RSS 2.0)" href="http://example.com/rss.xml"  />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Company&#39;s Blog (RSS 2.0)" href="http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/blogrss.xml"  />
```